# Testing buttons in react dynamically rendered with data from redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-testing-library

This is a simplified example I've made.

I have the following react component

**Test.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from '../app/hooks';
import { selectTest, setTest } from './testslice';

const Test: React.FunctionComponent = (props) => {

    const vals = useAppSelector(selectTest)
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(setTest(["2","3","4","5"]))
    },[])

  return <>
    {vals.map((v,i) => <button key={i}>{v}</button>)}
  </>;
};

export default Test;
```

And the following redux reducer slice

**testSlice.ts**

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { RootState } from "../app/store";

export interface AppState {
  test:string[]
}

const initialState: AppState = {
  test:[]
};



export const appSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'test',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setTest(state,action: PayloadAction<string[]>) {
        state.test = action.payload
    }
  },
});

export const {
  setTest,
} = appSlice.actions;

export const selectTest = (state: RootState) => state.test.test;


export default appSlice.reducer;
```

I would like to test the `Test` component and see, that the buttons are rendered with the values I've dispatched to the redux store (The length of values will be a fixed length)

**Test.test.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';



import { store } from '../app/store';
import Test from './TestComponent';

test('renders learn react link', () => {
  const { getByText } = render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Test/>
    </Provider>
  );

//Somehow test that the buttons rendered in <Test/> component have the values dispatched in the useEffect hook
  
});
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried ? Did you try to expect(getByText('1')).toBeTruthy() (same for each values) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the [official documentation of testing `redux` with `react` and `testing library`](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests#components). The idea is to create a `preloadedState` which gets injected in your application from inside the test. You can then test for the objects of this `preloadedState` and see if the objects are rendered correctly. After setting up the helper render function in the docs above with e.g.

```
...
import appReducer from 'PATH/testSlice';
...
store = configureStore({ reducer: { test: appReducer }, preloadedState })
```

you can then do:

```
...
import { render } from '../../test-utils'
...
const givenState = { test: ["1", "2", "3"] }
const { getByText } = render( <Test/>, { preloadedState: givenState });
for(const val of givenState.test) {
   expect(getByText(val).toBeVisible();
}
```

For more "integration"-testing, you could also mock return values from functions that finally populate the state, e.g. fetch calls. That way, you would not need to create a `preloadedState` but mock the fetch calls, whose objects you would use for assertions.

Comment: I realized also, that I can directly call `store.getState()` in my tests, but don't know if that is the best approach.

Comment: It depends on what you want to test exactly. If you stay on a more unit test level without providing props directly, you might mock and access a store/state. However, if you want to test integration with the store and therefore test the reducer as well, you don't access the state directly. Then you might mock the source of data, e.g. a network request that is expected to be executed.